# Cursor within cursor to compare same column's record not executing

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am working on small PL/SQL program which compare the column record with itself using cursor. When I execute the code it takes long time seems like falling in endless loop.

```
Table Data :-

STD
----
 2
 1
 4
 3
 6
 5
 8
 7
 10
 9
 12
 11
```

below is my code:-

```
declare 
s number;
s1 number;
c number := 0;
cursor c1 is (select std from data);
cursor c2 is (select std from data);
begin
open c1;
loop
    fetch c1 into s;
     open c2;
        loop
            fetch c2 into s1;
            if s < s1
            then    
                c := c + 1;
           end if;
        end loop;
     insert into con values(c);
     close c2;       
end loop;
close c1; 
end;
/
```

Expected result :-

```
C=10
C=10
C=8
C=8
C=6
C=6
C=4
C=4
C=2
C=2
C=0
C=null
```

Comment: It seems that your approach could be simplified, so please post some sample data and needed result,with some explanation, to help people to understand what you need to do

Comment: So we have starting data. If you could even post the needed result for this data, it would be easier for people to suggest you a simpler solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add

`EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;`

`EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;`

after corresponding fetch. e.g.

```
declare 
s number;
s1 number;
c number := 0;
cursor c1 is (select std from data);
cursor c2 is (select std from data);
begin
open c1;
loop
    fetch c1 into s;
    EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
     open c2;
        loop
            fetch c2 into s1;
            EXIT WHEN c2%NOTFOUND;
            if s < s1
            then    
                c := c + 1;
           end if;
        end loop;
     insert into con values(c);
     close c2;       
end loop;
close c1; 
end;
/
```

Comment: still falling in endless loop

Comment: @JayDesai could you try  the same code but  without `insert` clause.  May be your program 'hangs' because of a table lock?

Comment: @JayDesai This is not an endless loop, but a very poor perfoming code that may even hang on a large set of data.

Comment: exactly. The point of using this type of  code is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you are assuming that your data are ordered somehow the way you posted; given this, you need to count, for each value in your data set, the number of values greater than the current one and appearing after the current row.

Say we can consider your data sample with an additional column (`ID`) to give the order:

```
create table data(ID, std) as (
    select  1,  2 from dual union all
    select  2,  1 from dual union all
    select  3,  4 from dual union all
    select  4,  3 from dual union all
    select  5,  6 from dual union all
    select  6,  5 from dual union all
    select  7,  8 from dual union all
    select  8,  7 from dual union all
    select  9, 10 from dual union all
    select 10,  9 from dual union all
    select 11, 12 from dual union all
    select 12, 11 from dual
)
```

If I understand well your need, you can avoid PLSQL and cursor and get the result with a single query:

```
select d1.std, count(d2.id)
from data d1
       left outer join data d2
         on ( d1.ID < d2.ID and d2.std > d1.std)
group by d1.std, d1.id   
order by d1.ID
```

On the sample data, this gives:

```
   STD     COUNT(D2.ID)
---------- ------------
     2           10
     1           10
     4            8
     3            8
     6            6
     5            6
     8            4
     7            4
    10            2
     9            2
    12            0
    11            0
```